# Which process is responsible for TCP in Linux

Tags: linux, tcp

I'm interested to know which process in Linux actually gets information from the Network layer on the receiving side, applies all the TCP-related logic(TCP-level error check, segments acknowledgement, etc.) and puts it into receive buffer of the waiting connection?

On the other hand, which process receives information which was sent to the socket by the host application in order to process it and send to the network layer?

Maybe I don't understand this process correctly... Please, help

Comment: it's inside kernel, not user space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of code, it is code that exists in kernel space that actually handles the implementation of TCP upward from NIC drivers. The Linux kernel is aware of your network hardware and abstracts it into a set of link adapters. The TCP/UDP/IP stack is then aware of these "link" devices and is further abstracted to Linux/Unix level concepts such as sockets.

Processes access this functionality through system calls to the kernel. While the concept of a process in Linux is isolated or gated from the kernel it is technically true that each process is able to access this functionality through system calls.

This means that when data is received on the NIC its the kernel handling TCP. When an application receives data out of the buffer that process is handling TCP although only in a gated way through system calls in kernel space/memory through its initiation of a system call.

Because Linux is preemptive even calls into kernel space are part of at least how the kernel keeps track of that processes share of time so you might technically consider TCP to be a part of every process. But if you consider only code that belongs to that processes memory space (user space applications) then only the kernel handles TCP.

Keep in mind that Linux/Unix incorporates some socket functionality which is abstracting TCP/IP into libraries that are linked to when compiling an application thus would be in its memory space. Such as memory structures used to represent IP addresses.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is very confused. It is predicated on describing TCP/IP in terms of the OSI model. And that's just not possible. TCP/IP pre-dates OSI and was never intended to comply with this model. Accessing this page using a HTTP/2 capable browser you have at least 4 separate session layers, compression is being handled in at least 3 different layers of the stack, not to mention WAN optimization on the network itself.

> Which process is responsible for TCP in Linux

TCP happens in the kernel. Not in user processes. So depending on your frame of reference, all of them or none of them.

Comment: It could be predicated upon reading Douglas Comer's book on _Internetworking with TCP/IP_.

Comment: Don't we have some license to interpret what the asker means when they use incorrect terminology rather than simply correcting their misuse of terminology without actually answering the question?

Comment: This is a very non-constructive answer. Nowhere does the question even mention OSI model, sessions, web browsers, or other things that take up the first 4/5 of the answer. And assuming that models are even coming up in the asker's thoughts, who's to say they're not thinking of the TCP/IP model, which **does** include a "network layer"/"link layer".

Comment: That TCP/IP is handled in the kernel is really an implementation detail. E.g, early TCP/IP on MS-DOS was purely in userland.